# Developer Information Update In Process on itunes connect

Tags: app-store-connect

"Note: Your developer information update is in process. Until it's complete,  the updated Program License Agreement may not go into effect."

That error is on itunes connect for my account. I have changed my account from personal to business weeks ago. It wont let me update the information for the iap in my app.

Any help would be appreciated as this is time sensitive. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: It was something to do with tax information for the business account.